# Printing a value for the space character?

Tags: c++

I am making a program to translate English to Morse Code, using a series of conditional statements. I am using the following function:

```
void english (char text1){
    if (text1=='a'||text1=='A'){cout<<".- ";}
    else if (text1=='b'||text1=='B'){cout<<"-... ";}
.
.
.
    else if (text1=='z'||text1=='Z'){cout<<"--.. ";}
    else if (text1==' '){cout<<"/";}
}
```

There's one very simple problem. I cannot get my program to print anything for when there is a space character in the input; it should print a slash. I also tried `else if (isspace(text1))` instead of `else if (text1==' ')`, but with no luck.

Comment: Please show how you call the function and give an example input where it does not work.

Comment: so what happens if `text1==' '`? BTW, a `switch(text1) { ... }` may be more appropriate here.

Comment: How are you reading the input? `std::cin >> charVariable`? If so, you might want to consider using `std::noskipws`

Comment: @Walter: Or a table of values... `const char* encoded[] = { ".- ", "-... ", ... }; char ch = tolower(input); if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') { return encoded[ch - 'a']; } else ...`

Comment: @user3556908 You may want to read `char` wise from the input stream. The `std::istream& operator<<(std::istream&, char)` operator function still uses whitespace characters as delimiter.

Comment: @David std::noskipws worked. I was trying to get the program to read from an input file using inFile>>text1 (inFile as the previously inputted input file, and text1 as my function) but it was skipping the spaces so thank you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You probably meant `operator>>` :)

Comment: Consider using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` and a `switch` statement.  A better solution would be a **look up table**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the function you have posted code for.  The problem is in the code which reads input.  You may for example need to use std::getline(cin, line) to get an entire line with whitespace intact, or perhaps easier, get one character at a time:

```
for (char ch; cin.get(ch); ) {
  english(ch);
}
```